# Firebase notification Service not registered when sending message

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I get these errors and app crashes when i send message to my device through firebase cloud messaging.

```
W/ConnectionTracker: Exception thrown while unbinding
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzji@e44a084
        at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1331)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1495)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:648)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.stats.ConnectionTracker.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.3.0:55)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.stats.ConnectionTracker.unbindService(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.3.0:50)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzio.zzag(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:245)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzio.zzal(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:262)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzio.zzc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:336)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzir.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzai.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:7)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzfs.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:21)
```

I followed the instructions step by step from this page https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: make sure you have set up firebase components properly , did you add the gson file generated ?

Comment: Yes i completed the procedure and firebase showed me a message saying that the connection established using the json file

Comment: are you using the firebase messaging service class ?

Comment: public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService like this and import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

Comment: make sure you have the service class to your manifest file

Comment: Damn it was like this .MyFirebaseMessagingService in manifest thats why it crashed! Thanks a lot! This was driving me crazy!

Comment: i'm glad this helped mate :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simply solve this issue you should add your firebase messaging service class to your manifest file , in the application tag , add this code snippet

```
<service
     android:name=".YourFirebaseMessagingService" // here you need to put your class name
     android:exported="false">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
     </intent-filter>
 </service>
```

Comment: I'm using Flutter. What is the class name?

Comment: this code is posted was for android ,for flutter , i really have no idea but the class is a servicce called FirebaseMessagingService , you can look it up

Comment: @Mr.ZeroOne, I am also facing the same issue. Do you have solution for it?

Answer (score 2):

this is happen from "firebase_admob" package. Change it to old version

In my case, firebase_admob: 0.10.2 was the problem.

Comment: Ah thanks, mate. you literally saved my life :P
and yeah you can use the `admob_flutter` package as an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like to me that you need to add this implementation inside your project dependencies:

```
dependencies {
   ...
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.4.0'
   ...
}
```